# clearing/refreshing all the fields using onchange event in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I have a set of code, in which i have a drop down list, and have 6-8 text fields below it. Now whenever i change the option, i want all the fields to be refreshed, i mean the fields must be made empty....

What i have tried:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#typed').change(function() {

$('#fieldid1').val("");
$('#fieldid2').val("");
....
    })
});
```

But my question is can it be done using only a single line of code such that all the textboxes present will be cleared ????

Comment: You could give them a common class, and select that

Comment: oh ok thanks :) A great point indeed

Comment: or target them by their type, for instance 'form input'

Comment: @Mysteryos You could, but then all input elements would have their values emptied.

Comment: @billyonecan Ah yes. a ':not' selector will then have to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#typed').change(function () {
    $('input:text').val("");
});
```

Also, you can put a class to all the input fields you want to clear and do as follows:

```
$('#typed').change(function () {
    $('input.someclass').val("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give all your fields a common class name like `class='test3'` and then:

```
<input type="text" class="test3" >
<input type="text" class="test3" >
<input type="text" class="test3" >
<input type="text" class="test3" >
<input type="text" class="test3" >

<select id="btn3">
    <option value="volvo">111</option>
    <option value="saab">222</option>
    <option value="mercedes">333</option>
    <option value="audi">444</option>
</select>


 $("#btn3").change(function(){
     $(".test3").val("");
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/ac6Fr/)**

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a input type='reset' and hide it the form using jquery `.hide()`
2.`Trigger('click')` click of that input type.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').val("");
```

or

```
$('textarea').val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all your fields a common class name like `class='resetme'` then

```
$('#typed').change(function () {
    $('.resetme').val("");
});
```